# Analytic extension of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ complex domain

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, analytic-continuation

The analytic extension:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\int_0^1\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}dx$$

I was wondering for what values of $n$ does this extend to, mainly complex values of $n$.

I know it is defined for $n=0$,

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^0-1}{x-1}dx=\int_0^10dx=0$$

I also know it is not defined for $n<0$

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{-n}-1}{x-1}dx=\int_0^1\frac{-1}{x^n}dx\to\infty$$

But what about $n\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The integral converges iff $\mathrm{Re}\;n > 0$.  (Apart from $n=0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural way to extend
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k, \quad n=1,2,\ldots,
$$ is to consider
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^z-1}{x-1}dx=\psi(z+1)+\gamma, \quad z>-1,
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and where $z \mapsto \psi(z+1)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), analytic over $(-1,\infty)$, deeply linked to the Euler gamma function
$$
\psi(z+1)=\frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}, \quad z>-1,
$$  and which has been [extensively](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) [studied](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.4#ii) since Euler's works ($1728$).

A meromorphic extension does exist,
$$
\psi(z+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{z+n}  
\right), \quad z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{\left\{-1,-2,-3 \ldots \right\}}.
$$

Comment: Does that mean it works for $z=-1/2$?

Comment: The answer is yes. One may prove that $\psi(1/2)=-\gamma-2\ln 2$. See here: http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.4#ii Thanks.